# HttpSessionStateBase losing property values of inherited type

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, httpsession

We are using HttpSessionStateBase to store messages in a set up similar to this working example:

```
public class HttpSessionMessageDisplayFetch : IMessageDisplayFetch
{
    protected HttpSessionStateBase _session;

    private IList<ICoreMessage> messages
    {
        get
        {
            if (_session[EchoCoreConstants.MESSAGE_KEY] == null)
                _session[EchoCoreConstants.MESSAGE_KEY] = new List<ICoreMessage>();

            return _session[EchoCoreConstants.MESSAGE_KEY] as IList<ICoreMessage>;
        }
    }

    public HttpSessionMessageDisplayFetch()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            _session = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
    }

    public void AddMessage(ICoreMessage message)
    {
        if (message != null)
            messages.Add(message);
    }

    public IEnumerable<IResultPresentation> FlushMessagesAsPresentations(IResultFormatter formatter)
    {
        var mToReturn = messages.Select(m => m.GetPresentation(formatter)).ToList();

        messages.Clear();

        return mToReturn;
    }
}
```

When we pass in a QualityExplicitlySetMessage (which inherits from ICoreMessage, see below) it is saved correctly to messages.

[This is how the object looks after being inserted into the messages list, at the end of AddMessage(ICoreMessage message) above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLKxe.png)

But when we come to access it after changing controllers the inherited member's properties are null, which causes a variety of null reference exceptions.

[This is how the object now looks after we call FlushMessagesAsPresentations. I've commented out var mToReturn... as this tries to access one of these null ref properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQBAh.png)

I'd like to ask the following:

- Why is the HttpSessionStateBase failing to capture these values taken
  by the inherited type?
- Is this an issue in saving to the HttpSession or in retrieving?
- Is this anything to do with, as I suspect, inheritance?
- Or is the fact I'm potentially calling a new controller that dependency injects the HttpSessionMessageDisplayFetch causing an issue?

I'm a first-time poster so please let me know if I'm making any kind of faux pas - Super keen to learn! Any input is very welcome.

Some potentially useful code snippets:

**QualityExplicitlySetMessage**

```
public class QualityExplicitlySetMessage : QualityChangeMessage
{
    public QualityExplicitlySetMessage(IQPossession before, IQPossession after, IQEffect qEffect)
        : base(before, after, qEffect)
    {
        IsSetToExactly = true;
    }
}
```

**QualityChangeMessage** - Working example

```
public abstract class QualityChangeMessage : CoreMessage, IQualityChangeMessage
{
    protected PossessionChange Change;

    public PossessionChange GetPossessionChange()
    {
        return Change;
    }

    protected QualityChangeMessage(IQPossession before, IQPossession after, IQEffect qEffect)
    {
        Change = new PossessionChange(before, after, qEffect);
        StoreQualityInfo(qEffect.AssociatedQuality);
    }

    public override IResultPresentation GetPresentation(IResultFormatter formatter)
    {
        return formatter.GetQualityResult(this);
    }

    #region IQualityChangeMessage implementation

    public int LevelBefore
    {
        get { return Change.Before.Level; }
    }

    //... And so on with values dependent on the Change property.

}
```

**CoreMessage** - Working example

```
public abstract class CoreMessage : ICoreMessage
    {

    public string MessageType
    {
        get { return GetType().ToString(); }
    }

    public string ImageTooltip
    {
        get { return _imagetooltip; }
        set { _imagetooltip = value; }
    }

    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }

    public int? RelevantQualityId { get; set; }


    protected void StoreQualityInfo(Quality q)
    {
        PyramidNumberIncreaseLimit = q.PyramidNumberIncreaseLimit;
        RelevantQualityId = q.Id;
        RelevantQualityName = q.Name;
        ImageTooltip = "<strong>" + q.Name + "</strong><br/>" + q.Description + "<br>" +
                       q.EnhancementsDescription;
        Image = q.Image;
    }

    public virtual IResultPresentation GetPresentation(IResultFormatter formatter)
    {
        return formatter.GetResult(this);
    }
}
```

**UserController** - Working example.

```
public partial class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMessageDisplayFetch _messageDisplayFetch;

    public UserController(IMessageDisplayFetch messageDisplayFetch)
    {
        _messageDisplayFetch = messageDisplayFetch;
    }

    public virtual ActionResult MessagesForStoryletWindow()
    {
        var activeChar = _us.CurrentCharacter();
        IEnumerable<IResultPresentation> messages;

        messages = _messageDisplayFetch.FlushMessagesAsPresentations(_storyFormatter);

        var vd = new MessagesViewData(messages)
        {
            Character = new CharacterViewData(activeChar),
        };
        return View(Views.Messages, vd);
    }
}
```

Comment: R.I.P. minimal example :/

Comment: Hi deW1. This is a problem that could quite a number of causes and is likely the result of confused inheritance, so an MWE would not be conducive. That being said, I'll have a read over and reduce the size where I can.

Comment: Can you elaborate what does "after changing controllers" mean?

Comment: Hi @Andrei - Of course, sorry if this isn't clear enough. Saving the message and adding the message are called at two different times in execution, possibly not by the same instance of the UserController.